Set Vite host path to match Sail site URL
In my Laravel project I am outputting CSS/JS like so:
@vite('resources/sass/app.scss')

When I share the site with Laravel Sail, the built asset path becomes:
http://host.docker.internal/build/assets/app-D3Xhruhn.css

which doesn't work, the actual path is:
http://yf5n8g5vbc.laravel-sail.site:8080/build/assets/app-D3Xhruhn.css

Is there a way to tell Laravel/Vite to use the base path of the public shared site?
